# Threading priority workaround method

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a python application where I use threading for the I/O bound tasks (reading from two seperate input sensors). I am aware that becouse of the GIL it is not possible to set a priority to a thread however I feel like my problem simply must be common enought that someone has though of a decent workaround. As I run the application it uses the maximum computational power of the CPU and I assume that is the problem, however I can not work around using the full potential.

Now for the issue, I know that a specific sensor is sending data every ~24:th ms (might drift over time). However the time when the application reads the data for example in the following time-order:

```
Available data at time (s): 4.361776
Available data at time (s): 4.3772116
Available data at time (s): 4.4171033
Available data at time (s): 4.4250908
Available data at time (s): 4.4596746
Available data at time (s): 4.5154788
Available data at time (s): 4.5154788
Available data at time (s): 4.5254734
```

Which is basicly on average 24ms inbetween each measurement but they are read in "clumps". Does anyone have a workaround for the problem? I know that I could implement sort of a "guessing" algorith to estimate the actual time for the measurement based on the time for the previous measurements however that seems like a solution prone to unexpected errors.

Comment: Didn't get whats the problem exactly

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi  I need to know more exactly when the measurement is being made.

Comment: What do you mean by 'clumps'. Could you please share the code?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi The code is over 5000 lines in total but what I mean is that the application reads 3-4 messages in 10ms and then reads none in 100ms or so, while I know that the sensor is sending messages at 24ms +- 1ms,

Comment: ok. One possibility is that some kind of biffering is happening. Hard to tell without code.